# Ubuntu server 20.04 IPv6 DUID

Tags: networking, static-ip, client, dhcpv6

on an Ubuntu server acting as an DHCPv6 client with netplan set like this

```
renderer: networkd
dhcp6: true
```

I received an IPv6 address but I need the DUID to create a static lease on a router.

I did a lot of research on the internet but I found no answer.
All the mentioned files do not exist :

- `/var/lib/dhcp/` is empty
- `/etc/dhcp/dhclient6.conf` does not exist

I know that systemd-networkd generate DUID using the machine-id from the `/etc/machine-id` file.

We can change the way DUID is generated by editing `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf` [networkd.conf manpages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/networkd.conf.5.html)

I don't know where to find the DUID.

I can find it on my router (under OpenWRT) to be able to set a static lease.

Is it permanent ?

If for any reason, for example, I decide to install an dhcp server package on my server, is there a chance that the DUID will change ?

thank's

[edit 2021-04-15] I face this issue after installing pihole (which installed dnsmasq). The DUID change from something like `00020000...` to `00010000...`

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this yet?  I'm trying to do the exact same thing.

This blog suggests that netplan dhcpv6 doesn't support DUID but I can't find anything else concrete.
https://gist.github.com/Hermanverschooten/40c701b7f52e256502c9fe78473912e4

Comment: unfortunatly no. setting the lease id format, by editing `nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` `send lease-id-format = xxxxx` change nothing. To fix the problem, on client side, i installed dnsmasq.